# How do I make Bootstrap v4 look like v3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I'm looking to migrate to v4.

I previously included `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap-theme.min.css` in my HTML, but while migrating to v4, I couldn't find `bootstrap-theme.min.css` anymore, and I didn't know where it was or what alternatives there were.

Where can I get `bootstrap-theme.min.css` for the latest v4 release or the closest equivalent using vanilla Bootstrap (by only editing SCSS variables)?

**This question was originally posted on [Bootstrap's GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21078) by @pankajparkar**

Comment: I'd like to get this question re-opened, I have edited my question to try to include more details. This is a very valid question that was asked on the Bootstrap GitHub repository, by a fellow StackOverflow user (@PankajPanar). I think this was misunderstood because the author of the issue clearly wanted to use vanilla Bootstrap

Comment: Aren't you the "author of the issue"? Haven't you already answered your own question?

Comment: @ZimSystem No, I am not the author of the GitHub issue. I just reposted it here to help others, and yes I answered the question already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The separate theme (`bootstrap-theme.min.css`) has been removed from v4.

> Replaced the separate optional theme with configurable options via SCSS variables

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#global-changes

In order to get it to look a little more like v3 did, you have to add these SCSS variables as per the [v4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass-options):

```
$enable-gradients: true;
$enable-shadows: true;
```

and then re-compile the SCSS source.

**Note:** Don't forget to follow the [migration docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#by-component) in order to not get any components that aren't working or other migration surprises.

Answer (score 0):

As @wolfy said you should 1st compile `scss` by changing variable with values `$enable-gradients: true;` & `$enable-shadows: true;` to css would do create a bootstrap theme.

Since there is drastic change in `navbar` API your navbar styling would not work. You have to refer this Twitter Bootstrap [**navbar API**](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav)(alpha version) and correct your old html(you may end up spending few hours).

For more updates, you could keep eyes on this [github issue](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav)